# Change int value from another ViewController

Tags: xcode

I have an int value in my file1ViewController.m and i want to change this value form my file2ViewController.m. I tried to import the file, NSUserDefaults but i wasn't able to let it works.

Anyone can help me with the code? What is the simplest method to do this simple thing?

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Could you explain your question better/in greater detail?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to pass a reference to a `file1ViewController` object to a `file2ViewController` when it is pushed or presented.  The exact way of doing that depends on the relationship between those objects and how they are created and given control of the display.

Knowing the difference between classes, objects, and code files is a big step in the right direction.